# Is there a permission in MediaWiki to allow a user to edit discussions but not pages?

Tags: mediawiki, permissions

Is there a [permission](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#List_of_permissions) in MediaWiki that allows a user to edit a discussion but not a page?

That would enable anyone to, say, express a view, but only certain users (e.g. those with a confirmed email) to edit a page.

Comment: What do you mean by discussion? Do you mean the discussion page?

Comment: @Paul yes, the Discussion/Talk page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default permission, but the MediaWiki extension [TalkRight](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TalkRight) seems to do what you request. You use it by installing the extension and adding the following to LocalSettings.php.

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false; // Start by preventing users from editing anything
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['talk'] = true; // Let users edit talk pages
$wgGroupPermissions['emailconfirmed']['edit'] = true; // Let emailconfirmed users edit all pages
```

I'm not sure how well maintained that extension is or will be, so you should be able to do the same without extensions. (Note that I am unable to test any of this code, but it should work.) This also goes in LocalSettings.php.

```
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MAIN_TALK] = array('edittalk');

$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edittalk'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['emailconfirmed']['edit'] = true;
```

See also the MediaWiki docs for `$wgGroupPermissions` and `$wgNamespaceProtection`.